# How QVariant Works Internally?

Tags: qt, qvariant

I want to know, How QVariant can internally stores, int, QMap, QList,...

I mean what is the internal data-structure/Implementation? What is the overhead of storing and retrieving types (int, float) in QVariant?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A quick look at the code reveals that a `QVariant` is basically a `union` of several primitive types (`int`, `float` etc'), a `QObject` pointer, and a `void*` pointer for anything else that is not a `QObject` and not a primitive. There is also a type data member that allows it to know what's actually currently stored there. The overhead appears to be not much more than storing to a member of a struct, checking that for type compatibility and possibly making a conversion (int to float for instance)

Comment: As additional overhead, it also needs to store what the underlying type is.  This makes `QVariant` a total of _16 bytes_: 8 bytes (largest primitive type) + 4 bytes (type info) + 4 bytes (padding).

Comment: At least as of now, it has a pimpl. I think the size is now 32bytes, 16 for the `QVariant` and 16 for the  `QVariant::Private`. At least, that is what `sizeof` tells me. I have not counted them by hand.